# Array failed to know if it contains a string

Tags: c#, arrays

I must doing something wrong... But I can't figure it out!

I have an array with string in it. I'm trying to fins if the Array contains some words like `Sales` for example.

```
drillDownUniqueNameArray[0] = "[Sales Territory].[Sales Territories].[Sales Territory Group].&[North America]";//Inside the string array there is this string in index 0

drillDownUniqueNameArray.Contains("S")//Output false!

Array.IndexOf(drillDownUniqueNameArray,"S")//Output -1!  <--Fixed My answer

drillDownUniqueNameArray.Contains("[Sales Territory].[Sales Territories].[Sales Territory Group].&[North America]") //Output true!
```

I thouhgt Contains should find even part of the string..

How can I find if this array have `"S"` or `"Sales"` for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking if the array *contains* an element that's **exactly** `"S"` but I think you are *trying* to check whether the array *contains* an alement that **contains** an `"S"`.

You could achieve this by the following statement:

```
drillDownUniqueNameArray.Any( str => str.Contains ("S") )
```

Comment: I fixed my answer... I'm getting -1

Comment: +1 but explain reason too, if he was doing that way I suppose he didn't understand it.

Comment: @SimonC does Stephan was the first with this answer?

Answer (score 5):

You are asking if the array contains a string that exactly matches `"S"`.

What you want is to ask if any of the strings in the array contains the character `"S"`, something like:

```
drillDownUniqueNameArray.Any(v => v.Contains("S"))
```

Comment: I fixed my answer... I'm getting -1

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.
    drillDownUniqueNameArray[0].Contains("s");

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ:

```
var allWithSales = drillDownUniqueNameArray
    .Where(str => str.Contains("Sales"));
```

ignoring the case:

```
var allWithSalesIgnoreCase = drillDownUniqueNameArray
     .Where(str => str.IndexOf("sales", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

If you want to find all that contain a **word** "Sales"(`String.Split()` = white-space delimiter)):

```
var allWordsWithSales = drillDownUniqueNameArray
    .Where(str => str.Split().Contains("Sales", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Now you can enumerate the query with `foreach` or use `ToArray()` or `ToList` to create a collection:

```
foreach(string str in allWithSales)
    Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are finding it in the array, but you should find the word in the string.

Use following if you want to check:

```
drillDownUniqueNameArray.Any(x=>x.Contains("Sales"));
```

Use following if want to get the strings which contains "Sales"

```
drillDownUniqueNameArray.Where(x=>x.Contains("Sales"));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do it like this:

drillDownUniqueNameArray.Contains("S")

it's not gonna check the values, you must do it like this:

drillDownUniqueNameArray[0].Contains("S") or drillDownUniqueNameArray.First().Contains("S")

like this way it checks the values inside the array not the arrays itself